# How to start a django project on cloud9?

Tags: python, django, cloud9-ide, c9.io

I just created a django workspace in cloud9. It gives me an empty folder with the project name with nothing on it. What commands do I need to type to start a django project and get coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They provide you with an README.md to understand how to use it, and a button to Run your project in their user interface.

Here's an example:

[image]

The arrow indicates where you can click to Run your project.

The section highlighted shows how to use it from the terminal.